# migration rejected closed question any way to edit?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, editing, closed-questions

This question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13737/best-way-to-model was migrated from *game dev* with the tag of [untaged](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untaged). Is there any way to retag that question now? On most closed questions there is still the option to edit them, why is this question locked? I would say that this question could be deleted all together, but again for some reason it is locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you can't edit it (I can as a moderator). It's probably because it was migrated then closed (?). Every question needs at least one tag, so what probably happened was that when the moderator from GD.SE migrated it he dubiously selected the [untagged](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag.

It's a good idea to keep closed questions around. They help show the community what's not accepted here. (Unless if it's spam, etc, of course).

If you want it changed, let me know. I guess the [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling) tag would work.

Comment: yes, if you think it a good idea to keep the question around, then please do re tag it.